# query to mongoDB doesnt work when i use an array variable , but works when i explicitly write the array in the AND query (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

can anyone explain as to why does this query to mongoDB works when i write the array explicitly like this in the AND operator

```
async function getAds(queryParams) {
        return ad = await ads.Ad.find()
        .and( { tags : { $all: ["karachi","lahore"] }}));
    }
```

but doesnt work when i retrieve the array of tags from the query params and put directly in the AND operator?
like this

```
async function getAds(queryParams) {
            return ad = await ads.Ad.find()
            .and( { tags : { $all: queryParams.tags }}));
        }
```

and yes i checked with ' and also ", and also i checked queryParams.tags, it is exactly equals to ["karachi","lahore"]

Comment: turn up the log verbosity on the server so you can see exactly what query is received on that side.

Comment: @Joe i already logged and checked the query . as i mentioned the query is recieved in array form ["karachi","lahore"], which means it it recieved as an array but it only works when i hardcode the array instead of putting queryParams.tags variable

Comment: Can we see the log entry from a time it didn't work?